# binding/bcrypt_lib.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an express js application. I want to run it consistently on server. So I used PM2. When I am running the application in staging environment then it is running good. But when I am running it on production server, it gives following error:

```
Error: The module '/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
0|server   | was compiled against a different Node.js version using
0|server   | NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
0|server   | NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
0|server   | the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
0|server   |     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:18)
0|server   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
0|server   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
0|server   |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
0|server   |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/home/iron/.nvm/versions/node/v13.1.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:70:39)
0|server   |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
0|server   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/iron/Documents/chat-api-stg/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
0|server   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
0|server   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
0|server   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)


Versions:
node v13.1.0
nvm v0.32.1
npm v6.12.1
pm2 v4.1.2
```

I have python installed on both environments with v2.7.12.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try removing `node_modules` and running `npm i` again. If that doesn't help run `npm rebuild` as the error message suggest

Comment: I have already tried it many times. but got same error.

Comment: have you cleared npm cache before running `npm i` again?

Comment: Yes I cleared the cache before installing npm

Comment: I'm guessing that your Node and NPM versions are different on staging and prd environments?